# Is "might" good here?

Tags: word-choice

Is "might" good here? Could the sentence be phrased better?

I might be in a wheelchair, but I'm not going to let it stop me from chasing my dream.

Answer (score 1):

You could say "Though I am in a wheelchair, I won't let it stop me...", but the way you expressed it is good too.
"Though I am..." means that I am in a wheelchair now.
"I might be in a wheelchair someday..." could be expressing a future possibility, but as you phrased it, it  will be taken as meaning that I am in the wheelchair now.

Comment: google provides supporting examples google provides similar examples https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I+might+be+in+a+wheelchair%2C+but%22

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that your sentence sounds totally normal and idiomatic to the average contemporary speaker (at least Br.Eng).  For the long answer, you could delve into previous posts on might vs may [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/389/107915) or on [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/7/361942) stackexchange.

Comment: Personally, I would prefer _I may be in a wheelchair_, as the speaker _is_ in one. I would reserve _might_ for hypothetical situations - _If I hadn't landed on something soft, I might be in a wheelchair by now._